# Displaying Custom Symbols in ArcGIS runtime

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

Hi i am new to arcgis and i want to display my custom symbol of 3d type with .obj format on a layer of data, i would like to display this particular symbol in all of the layer data's 2d points.

I know how to convert 2D Points using renderer to 3D
I also know that to convert the custom made symbol into arcgis runtime i will have to use model scene symbol.
I thought that publishing the symbol and using it would work but i came to know that it is the process for javascript api not runtime

Can anyone tell me how to use the custom made symbol into the layer of data?

Answer (score 0):

First, let me clarify that you cannot use 3D model symbols to symbolize layers in map(2D). But if you have custom symbols, you can use those symbol in ArcGIS Pro and create a mobile stylx file. Then you can open the stylx file in runtime to symbolize the features. See following topics for more information

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/net/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology.SymbolStyle.html

- Creating styles in ArcGIS Pro
  https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/tree/main/src/Forms/Shared/Samples/Symbology/SymbolsFromMobileStyle

Comment: Hi, i never said i was using it for a map, i was using it for a scene, it can be done through zipping a 3d file and uploading it to arcgis and then unpacking it and using it in the app, i was under the impression that the styles can be only used in arcgis javascript api but i will try for runtime like you mentioned the article i followed was

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/3d-gis/how-to-publish-web-styles-with-3d-symbols/

Comment: I still need suggestion for importing 3D symbols in ArcGIS Runtime .NET

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry for some reason I thought you were trying to use 3D symbols in 2D.

You can directly use obj file as a model symbol in runtime.  Pass in the URI of the symbol or save a local copy of .obj file and create modelscenesymbol pointing to that obj

`var ms = await ModelSceneSymbol.CreateAsync(new Uri(@"D:/TestData/cube.obj"),10.0);`

Comment: i have tried this and a small correction it's not Uri,it's System.Uri when we are using in wpf , my objective is to use it in a xamarin app which makes it necessary to have the 3d object online, and the way it's proposed in arcgis is to zip the object and publish it online which will be downloaded as a zipped files and unzipped by ussing 6 different classes